# How to get unchecked checkbox value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have created bellow script to select/deselect multiple check-box and store selected check-box value in hidden filed. Now I need your small help to complete this things. When user deselect any check-box I want that deselected check-box value to perform some task.

**My JS Code:**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
function toggle_chkbox(source,group,lbl) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(group);

    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
    {
        var chkid = '#'+lbl+i;

        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

        if(jQuery(chkid).hasClass('c_on') && checkboxes[i].checked == false  )
        {
            jQuery(chkid).removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');
        }
        else if(jQuery(chkid).hasClass('c_off') && checkboxes[i].checked == true  )
        {
            jQuery(chkid).removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');
        }
    }
    updateTextArea();       
}

function updateTextArea() {   
    var allVals = [];
    jQuery('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
        allVals.push((i!=0?"":"")+ jQuery(this).val());
     });
        jQuery('#textValue').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);
     }
     jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
});
```

**My Live Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Checkbox</title>
<style type="text/css">
.has-js .label_check, .has-js .label_radio {
    padding-left: 34px;
}
.has-js .label_check {
    background: url(http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/check-off.png) no-repeat;
}
.has-js label.c_on {
    background: url(http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/check-on.png) no-repeat;
}
.has-js .label_check input, .has-js .label_radio input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
function toggle_chkbox(source,group,lbl) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(group);

    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
    {
        var chkid = '#'+lbl+i;

        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

        if(jQuery(chkid).hasClass('c_on') && checkboxes[i].checked == false  )
        {
            jQuery(chkid).removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');
        }
        else if(jQuery(chkid).hasClass('c_off') && checkboxes[i].checked == true  )
        {
            jQuery(chkid).removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');
        }
    }
    updateTextArea();       
}

function updateTextArea() {   
    var allVals = [];
    jQuery('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
        allVals.push((i!=0?"":"")+ jQuery(this).val());
     });
        jQuery('#textValue').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);
     }
     jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
});
</script>

<div class="taglist">
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-01" id="lbl-box-posts1"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-01" class="chkBX" value="1" type="checkbox" /> 2D Animation </label>
  <br />
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-02" id="lbl-box-posts2"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-02" class="chkBX" value="2" type="checkbox" /> 3D Animation </label>
  <br />
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-03" id="lbl-box-posts3"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-03" class="chkBX" value="3" type="checkbox" />  Animatronics </label>
  <br />    
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-04" id="lbl-box-posts4"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-04" class="chkBX" value="4" type="checkbox" /> Architectural </label>
  <br />
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-05" id="lbl-box-posts5"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-05" class="chkBX" value="5" type="checkbox" /> Cartoon </label>
  <br />
    <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-06" id="lbl-box-posts6"><input name="ck-box-posts[]" id="checkbox-06" class="chkBX" value="all" type="checkbox" onchange="toggle_chkbox(this,'ck-box-posts[]','lbl-box-posts');" /> Check All </label>
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="textValue" id="textValue" >
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document;
    var safari = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') == 1) ? true : false;
    var gebtn = function(parEl,child) { return parEl.getElementsByTagName(child); };
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var body = gebtn(d,'body')[0];
        body.className = body.className && body.className != '' ? body.className + ' has-js' : 'has-js';

        if (!d.getElementById || !d.createTextNode) return;
        var ls = gebtn(d,'label');
        for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
            var l = ls[i];
            if (l.className.indexOf('label_') == -1) continue;
            var inp = gebtn(l,'input')[0];
            if (l.className == 'label_check') {
                l.className = (safari && inp.checked == true || inp.checked) ? 'label_check c_on' : 'label_check c_off';
                l.onclick = check_it;
            };
            if (l.className == 'label_radio') {
                l.className = (safari && inp.checked == true || inp.checked) ? 'label_radio r_on' : 'label_radio r_off';
                l.onclick = turn_radio;
            };
        };
    });
    var check_it = function() {
        var inp = gebtn(this,'input')[0];
        if (this.className == 'label_check c_off' || (!safari && inp.checked)) {
            this.className = 'label_check c_on';
            if (safari) inp.click();
        } else {
            this.className = 'label_check c_off';
            if (safari) inp.click();
        };
    };
    var turn_radio = function() {
        var inp = gebtn(this,'input')[0];
        if (this.className == 'label_radio r_off' || inp.checked) {
            var ls = gebtn(this.parentNode,'label');
            for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
                var l = ls[i];
                if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
                l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
            };
            this.className = 'label_radio r_on';
            if (safari) inp.click();
        } else {
            this.className = 'label_radio r_off';
            if (safari) inp.click();
        };
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for not creating jsFiddle or jsbin as I am getting error on that. :(

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".taglist :not(:checked)").each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
}
```

Like this you can get all the unchecked values and u can store it in an array or perform any operations on it as u want...Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 1):

you can bind a onChange function to the checkboxes and perform needed actions there:

```
$(<selector>).on("change",function(){
    //doThings 
});
```

like in your sample code:

```
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    var chkid = '#'+lbl+i;
    $(chkid).on("change",function(){
        //do things
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how to get unchecked check box value? Can you guide me?

Comment: i don't really know what you mean by that....just checking `if(!checkboxes[i].checked)` does not work for you?